# Why does Firebase take forever to complete the same function after redeploying an app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, next.js

### Summary

We are building an app that's hosted in Firebase. The app is built with react and next.js, and next (and thus, the app) is served to the client through a Firebase Cloud Function. I noticed that, after we redeployed the app (usually, because we are releasing a new version of it) the function that serves the app to the client takes an *unacceptable* amount of time to serve the app. Before the re-deploy, for example, executions took around half a second (see Fig 1), and after the re-deploy, around 36 seconds (see Fig 2). Why is this happening?

Figure 1: Prior to Redeploy
[image]

Figure 2: After Redeploy
[image]

### Code Sample

This is the code block (from `index.js` in Firebase Functions) that's responsible for serving the app to clients via a Cloud Function:

```
/**
 * Environmental value
 * @type {boolean}
 */
var dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
/**
 * ServerApp
 * @type {DevServer}
 */
var app = next({
  dev: false,
  conf: { distDir: `${path.relative(process.cwd(), __dirname)}/next` },
})
/**
 * Get request handler
 */
var handle = app.getRequestHandler()

/**
 * SSR
 * @type {HttpsFunction}
 */
exports.next = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // log the page.js file that is being requested
  console.log("File: " + req.originalUrl)

  return app.prepare().then(() => handle(req, res))
})
```

### Tech Stack

- "firebase": "^7.14.4"
- "firebase-admin": "^8.12.1"
- "firebase-functions": "^3.8.0"
- "react": "^16.8.6"

#### Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Its seems like you are experiencing cold start with Cloud Functions. As far as I'm aware, you can't avoid it since your functions need to be initialized the first time they are called after redeploy. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM) is a video about cold start and how to minimize its impact on your app.